# Play Framework [2.4.x] how to address public assets in a sub module's routing file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

This previous question may serve as a baseline for what "submodules" mean for the purpose of the current discussion: [Play Framework [2.4.x] Working with Sub Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702008/play-framework-2-4-x-working-with-sub-modules)

If you understand a Play submodule then given that context how does one enter the routing entry on the submodule to expose assets from a "public" folder?

Whenever I attempt to make a basic entry (as follows) my entire root module fails to compile a single route and yet I get no "usable" error or other indicator as to what might have happened.

```
GET   /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The compiler errors occur even if I comment out the entry in the root project.

As all my sub modules controllers have a prefix I tried that (of course)

```
GET   /assets/*file  controllers.submodule.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Alas that doesn't work either but at least I get a useful error telling me the `type Assets is not a member of package controllers.submodule`

Any suggestions?

PS: Yes I've also tried taking the entry out of the root's routing file  in case it was just a name space collision...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create an Assets controller in your submodule controllers package:

```
package controllers.submodule

class Assets extends AssetsBuilder(DefaultHttpErrorHandler)
```

Then declare a route for this controller in the router file (it should be named submodule.routes) of your submodule:

```
GET    /submodule/public/*file    controllers.submodule.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

It is better to prefix the route with the name of your submodule to avoid route colision in case you have other submodules name with static route entry.

One more thing: all your static files are hosted in the "lib" folder of your root module:

```
lib/submodule/css...
lib/submodule/js...
```

So you have to update your views like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@controllers.submodule.routes.Assets.versioned("lib/submodule/js/your-submodule-script.js")"></script>
```

**EDIT:** don't forget to add this to your route file (named routes) of your root module

```
-> / submodule.routes
```

Comment: In the main routes file (the routes feel for the main project) I have this little gem: `->  /submoduleNAME submodule.Routes` which essentially gives an alias of the submodule from the external perspective. Curious as to whether or not that will apply but thinking out loud I suspect it doesn't even matter...

Comment: And where might one find the error handler? `not enough arguments for constructor AssetsBuilder: (errorHandler: play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler)controllers.AssetsBuilder.`

Comment: I didn't mentioned it but yes you have to add this line to the route file of your root module. I just edited my answer

Comment: hmm...if you are using play 2.4 you should use `Assets extends AssetsBuilder(DefaultHttpErrorHandler) in the Asserts controller`

Comment: Ah - that would be `play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler` -- compiles at least so now I'll see if it works...

Comment: Strange - I can't seem to connect the dots to an actual (static) file. I do seem to get a different error at times however - one of `No router defined` instead of `Action not found` followed by the list of routes tried. I've tried both the `.at` and the `.versioned` methods along with may incantations of the path(s) on both ends of the routing statement.

Comment: Currently hitting this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/z3OKPdfyocM (which it seems you may have already accounted for...)

Comment: This is not quiet what I'm seeing. First I have to change the raw URL as follows: http://localhost:9000/SUBMODULE_REF_1/assets/lib/SUBMODULE_REF_2/favicon.png SUBMODULE_REF_1 is the entry in the root routes file and SUBMODULE_REF_2 is the actual submodule name. I do NOT have to place the files into an actual directory called `lib` -- took me many hours to find a single file so I'm not sure the above answer is conveying the full extent of what needs to be done clearly.

Comment: Actually you don't have to create a lib folder. Play generates all the static content for you into the `target/web/public/main/lib/submodule` folder for every submodule instead of `target/web/public/main` folder for the root module's static files.

Comment: Your answer was helpful for me. However, there are two details I would suggest to look into: a) the route at the end is missing a slash, right? Should be "-> / submodule.routes". b) the 'object Assets ...' implies that InjectedRoutesGenerator setting is not used, which is now (Play 2.4) recommended. With InjectedRoutesGenerator it needs to be 'class Assets ...' to compile.

Comment: @akauppi point b) of your remark helped me solved my problem as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985108/play-framework-2-4-x-module-route-specific-name-fails-with-assets-is-not-a Feel free to put it as answer to my question, I'll be pleased to acknowledge it.

Comment: @akauppi, you're right on your 2 points, I just edited the answer