# Play Framework [2.4.x] - Module route specific name fails with `Assets is not a member of package`

Tags: playframework, module, routes, playframework-2.4

I try to **provide module specific routing** that can be included in Play applications using the standard route file `conf/routes` as:

```
-> /psmod1 com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.Routes
```

Compilation error obtained:

> **type** Psmod1Assets **is not a member of package**
>   com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl

To accomplish this I followed two steps as instructed in the official documentation at [Assets and controller classes should be all defined in the controllers.admin package](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects#Assets-and-controller-classes-should-be-all-defined-in-the-controllers.admin-package)

**1. Define Assets and controller classes in their own package**

Define Assets class `Psmod1Assets.scala` as:

```
package com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl

import play.api.http.LazyHttpErrorHandler

object class Psmod1Assets extends controllers.AssetsBuilder(LazyHttpErrorHandler)
```

> The above **object definition replacement by class fixes the problem**

**2. Splitting the route file**

Define module specific route file `/conf/com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.routes` as:

```
# Routes
# Home page
GET   /                com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path    
GET   /assets/*file    com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.Psmod1Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

If you like you can check or clone the code of my small test project on github:

- Online:    https://github.com/refond/psmod1/tree/routing_issue
- With git:  `git clone -b routing_issue https://github.com/refond/psmod1.git`

The project is **configured to work** using standard `controllers.Assets`.
Go to `/conf/com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.routes` file (check it at [com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.routes](https://github.com/refond/psmod1/blob/routing_issue/conf/com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.routes)) and replace line with `controllers.Assets` by line with `com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.Psmod1Assets` to reproduce the compilation error.

I already checked the following resources:

- Looks like a duplicate but the approved answer does not address the current problem [Play Framework [2.4.x] how to address public assets in a sub module's routing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595309/play-framework-2-4-x-how-to-address-public-assets-in-a-sub-modules-routing-fi)
- Interesting but outdated: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363
- General https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Modules

Comment: object instead of class in Psmod1Assets definition was the culprit! As pointed out by a comment of [akauppi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14455/akauppi) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595309/play-framework-2-4-x-how-to-address-public-assets-in-a-sub-modules-routing-fi

Answer (score 0):

Assets **class** Psmod1Assets.scala definition must be ... a class not an object:

```
package com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl

import play.api.http.LazyHttpErrorHandler

class Psmod1Assets extends controllers.AssetsBuilder(LazyHttpErrorHandler)
```

This relates to the Play 2.4 recommended InjectedRoutesGenerator setting which requires the built Assets to be a class to benefit from dependency injection. See official documentation at [ScalaRouting#Dependency-Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/ScalaRouting#Dependency-Injection)

Be aware that the official documentation seems not to be completely consistent with this change yet an may still state `object` instead of `class`:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects#Assets-and-controller-classes-should-be-all-defined-in-the-controllers.admin-package

My small test project on github mentionned in the problem description is not updated to work with the custom `com.escalesoft.psmod1.ctrl.Psmod1Assets`